# Existence of a periodic solution using Poincaré-Bendixson with a parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the following system,

$$  \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \dot{x}=x+y-x^3-\alpha xy^2 \\
  \dot{y}=y-x-x^2y-y^3
 \end{array}
 \right. $$

the aim is to prove that there exists at least a periodic solution for every value of $\alpha$ (using Poincaré-Bendixson) and to calculate such solution for $\alpha=1$.

I have proved that the only fixed point when $\alpha\in(0,2)$ is the origin $(0,0)$ but I don't know how to apply Poincaré-Bendixson.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, you should do [the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267978/87697) with your problem: convert to polar coordinates and find annulus at boundary of which trajectories behave as on canonical picture for Poincaré-Bendixson theorem.