# Generalizing an application of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

I was looking for applications of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem and on this site I have found several examples almost all similar to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2267695/691503). So I tried to make a quite natural generalization
$$
\begin{cases}
     x'=ax+by-x(mx^2+ny^2)\\
     y'=-bx+dy-y(px^2+qy^2)
\end{cases}
$$
when $(a-d)^2-4b^2<0$ holds, the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem ensures the existence of a limit cycle. But my question is this could this still achieve some kind of natural generalization? That is, for example, change $mx^2+ny^2$ for a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$ or degree $n$ or I don't know... any ideas? (along with some hint on how to test it or some reference)

This question has already been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/431232/171387) without much success, I would like to know your approach to this question, I know that there can be many approaches to a natural generalization.